# Multiple credentials prompts when remoting on server/Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-remoting, windows-server, invoke-command

When logging on windows server to check uptime and services, I am being logged through gateway, both server and gateway are require different credentials.

I am working on powershell script that does this automatically, but I can not find way how to use multiple credentials when invoking command.

I am not sure if there is solution on this in powershell

When doing that manually, I am logging directly on server and gateway automatically pops up, asking for credentials, when I enter them, another prompt to server credentials pops up, then I logon on server.

Thanks for advice :-)

$Cred1 = [pscredential]::new($User1,$Password1) #service account to target server
$Cred2 = [pscredential]::new($User2,$Password2) #gateway credentials

Invoke-Command -ComputerName xxx-ScriptBlock { xxx } -credential $Cred1

...is not working with $Cred1, cause gateway requires $cred2.

Comment: I would recommend you to read this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: In your Invoke-Command, pass the cred object for the server credentials in the scriptblock